# Does select in SQLite3 lock the database?

Tags: sqlite

I have one process constantly insert into a sqlite3 database and another process select from the sqlite3 database(slow sql).

Does sqlite3 lock the database on reads?

I want make sure every write success. Read fail is acceptable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [SQLite3 locking reference](http://www.sqlite.org/lockingv3.html) after start of transaction (BEGIN command), a SHARED lock will be acquired when the first SELECT statement is executed. Shared lock means that the database may be read but not written. A RESERVED lock will be acquired when the first INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement is executed.